# #1066 - Not unique table/alias: 'it_courses'

Tags: mysql

```
select staff_basicdetails.sname from  it_courses
inner join it_courses on it_courses.course_code = student_coursedetails.stcourse_name 
inner join staff_basicdetails on staff_basicdetails.s_code=it_courses.s_code
```

here join operation not working please suggest any solution regards this issue

Comment: You need to alias table `it_courses`. As it is right now MySQL cannot tell which table fields `course_code`, `s_code` come from.

Comment: @Giorgos Betsos please do share the answer

Comment: Something like `select staff_basicdetails.sname from  it_courses AS it1 inner join it_courses AS it2 ...`

Comment: Also, you are referencing table `student_coursedetails` but this table isn't specified anywhere in your query.

Comment: @Giorgos Betsos  no output at all

Comment: I'm guessing the from  it_courses should be from student_coursedetails